# Install and run application as service on Windows linux and MAC

Tags: java, linux, windows, windows-services, nsis

Hi all I have creates a Java stand alone application with Swing Now I wanted to distribute this application as .exe or .sh file. 
Also I wanted to install and start my application as service on Windows,Linux and MAC machines ?
so how can I

1. *How I can start my application as service on this OS.*
2. *How to create installer of my application so when I double click on it it will get installed and started as service on this OS.*

What I have done so far

I google around and I came across the tool called YAJSW, I followed the steps given in *[this](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId527639)* Quick Start topic and created wrapper class of my application and its works as intended on my machine, but I don't know how I can bundle this wrapper and distribute my application as .exe or .sh so that my application will get install and execute as service on my client machine.

any help or point to direction will be appreciated.. 
Thanks...

Comment: I would argue that this is in fact at least three questions in one. Windows and Linux have very different approaches to service management - I would expect OS X to differ as well...

Comment: Can you use tomcat to run your application? It's pretty similar on Linux & Windows and easy to install.

Tomcat will handler wrapper and everything else for you.

Answer (score 2):

try [install 4 j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html)
it can create the exe , setup the service , run batch files to create db and execute their query, manage path and environmental variable, and create your custom installer
 screen.
you can create multiplatform installer but i used it only in windows

Comment: Install4J does have support for service deployment, IIRC, but it should be pointed out that it is a commercial offering with a price...

Comment: you are creating .exe file why care for the open source, as for price try something start with tor...